How to convert slk file to xlsx file by C#
I have slk file and i want to convert it to xlsx file. I tried to search but i couldn't find any way.
I know that slk file is a text file but is there a way to convert it to xlsx file with MS excel installed or not using C# with winForms?

Maybe automating excel to open the .slk file and save it as .xlsx is the simplest way. Also, consider reading the .slk file as a text file and filter lines starting with C to retrieve value of cells only. Then write data in a .csv file or use an excel object to write it as .xlsx.
